# Standard Rate in Resource Center - Project Server 2013/Project Online

Tags: ms-project-server-2013, project-online

I have a standard rate set for a resource (ex. 50/hr) and that resource is assigned to several tasks on a project.  My question is this:  If the resource were to have a rate change, would the system be smart enough to track hours worked on tasks at the $50 rate and track hours worked at the new rate separately?

I had a resource working 24hrs at $50 on three tasks.  I then changed the rate to $25 to see what would happen.  It ended up changing the rate on the 24hrs of work on the 3 tasks to $25, but was hoping it would know that the 24hrs of work should have been at $50/hr and then any additional tasks would be calculated using $25.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in Project Professional, in the Resource Information palette, under the Costs Tab. You can get to this by opening the resource in Project Pro from the Resource Centre

[image]

Double Click on the Resource in Project Pro and you get the Resource Info dialog and under the Costs tab you can edit the five available rate cards, including effective dates.

[image]

If you know a rate change is coming you can set the effective date in the future, and Project will apply it appropriately.